# How to express "play on guitar"?

Tags: translation, verbs, expressions

I wanted to say the following:

> "I am trying to learn to play Mexican songs on the guitar."

I know how to express try to, but I am not sure about the rest. Perhaps

> メキシカンな歌{うた}でギターをひきますをするならびましょうとする。

Is that translation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「ギターでメキシコの歌{うた}を弾{ひ}くことを習おうとしています。」 is the literal translation.
Mexican songs:  メキシコの歌 （メキシコの曲）
  ※ If the song is an instrumental, you can use "曲{きょく}" instead of "歌".
play (a song) on (string or keyboard instrument): (instrument)で(歌)を弾{ひ}く

Comment: この learn to ~ は「～できるようになる」って意味でしょうね・・「弾くことを習う」 ではなく。。。　eg: learn to speak Japanese 日本語を話せるようになる.「弾けるようになろうとしてます」なんて直訳したら変でしょうけど。

Comment: Sorry, but why 「習おうとしています。」 and not「習おうしています。」? Isn't that the volitional?

Comment: ”Learn to”は「できるようになる」でしたね。すみませんでした。
「弾けるようになろうとしています (literal translation)」→ 「ギターでメキシコの歌を弾くことができるようになろうとがんばっています。(free translation)」

Comment: Ah, ok, got it.

Comment: >MKII
Yes, it's the volitional.  The to- infinitive has some patterns in translation into Japanese, and "try to + verb" is translated like 「"Verb-Volitional" +とする.」

Comment: It’s not always 引く though, can be another word depending on the instrument

Comment: ^ 漢字違うし・・・・・・・・